# Function module to export local table to excel

Tags: abap, alv

I am working on a program in Business Warehouse that allows you to map out all of your process chains by following the hierarchy of parent to sub-chains by using the rspcchain table. As of right now I have it printing the output to the screen, but would like to export this output to excel instead. I have been unable to find a function module that serves this purpose, so any help would be greatly appreciated

*note* - after learning about the SALV classes available I changed the code to display the table differently.

```
REPORT  Z_PC_VARIANT_MAPPING.

*Declaring types and variables
TYPES: BEGIN OF t_chains,
  chain_id LIKE  rspcchain-chain_id,
  variant LIKE rspcchain-variante,
END OF t_chains.

DATA: lt_rspcchain TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF t_chains,
      lwa_rspcchain TYPE t_chains,
      o_alv TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table,
      lx_msg TYPE REF TO cx_salv_msg.

TABLES: rspcchain.

*selection screen setup
SELECT-OPTIONS chain_id FOR rspcchain-chain_id.
SELECT-OPTIONS type FOR rspcchain-type.

*filling local table
SELECT chain_id variante
  FROM rspcchain  INTO TABLE lt_rspcchain
  WHERE chain_id IN chain_id AND
  type IN  type AND
  objvers = 'A'.

*original code to test printing output on screen
*LOOP AT lt_rspcchain INTO lwa_rspcchain.
*  skip.
*  WRITE lwa_rspcchain-chain_id.
*  WRITE lwa_rspcchain-variant.
*ENDLOOP.

IF sy-subrc NE 0. "sy-subrc = return code
  WRITE 'Data not found'.
ENDIF.


*loading data from local table into alv object table
TRY.
  cl_salv_table=>factory(
    IMPORTING
      r_salv_table = o_alv
    CHANGING
      t_table      = lt_rspcchain ).
  CATCH cx_salv_msg INTO lx_msg.
ENDTRY.

*calling display method to display table
o_alv->display( ).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SALV framework for this, it comes with a class to export whatever would be displayed to various formats, including .MHTML and .XML formats that are understood by Excel. The class `CL_SALV_TABLE` has a method `TO_XML` to support this; additionally, you might need the  `CL_SALV_BS_XML_UTILS` to handle the transformations. See the report `SALV_TEST_TABLE_DISPLAY_OR_XML` for example coding.

Comment: i'm interested in trying that, hopefully it is available in my system.

Comment: I just checked in SE37 and there are lots of ALV and SALV function modules available for use. Looks like this will be the right direction to go.

Comment: @Salmonerd It's not a function module, you'll have to use classes, but don't worry. You might search for a report named SALV*XML*, but I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: yep got it, i was able to do a little research on the SALV classes and have changed the code to now display the report using the SALV table class.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the ABAP2XLSX project.

http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/abap2xlsx

Not sure if all the necessary components exist in BW, but this is really the best solution for creating spreadsheets out of ABAP code that I have found.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following which will download a CSV file, which with the .xls extension opens flawlessly in Excel:

Convert `lt_rspcchain` to a csv internal table by calling `SAP_CONVERT_TO_CSV_FORMAT`

Figure out where the user wants to store the file by calling `cl_gui_frontend_services=>file_save_dialog( )`

Store the file by calling `cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_download( )`

I assume you will be able to find how these work by experience or through Google.

Comment: when i search for this function module in se37 it is not found.

Comment: SAP_CONVERT_TO_CSV_FORMAT cannot be found

Comment: Odd, you can also try working with `SAP_CONVERT_TO_TEX_FORMAT` or try to create an internal table with strings yourself.

Comment: This FM may not be in BW.  Not everything that can be found in ECC is.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add the GUI status with button save xls. For example:

```
"STATUS GUI
o_alv->set_screen_status( pfstatus = 'STANDARD' report = 'SAPLKKBL'     set_functions = o_alv->c_functions_all ).
```

Regards,
Diego.